# Capture image by Webcam in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webcam

I want to capture an image from webcam and save on server or send through ajax. And which would be better option from both and why ? Any available information is welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: `jquery-webcam-plugin`, how is that even a tag ?

Comment: it was a tag, i just mentioned it. I though i'll get some help :( Okay, I removed it. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this by following these steps

**Step #1**

Download Javascript Webcam project from [Here](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs)

**Step #2**

Extract solution and add this complete solution with your existing asp.net mvc application using

[Add Exiting Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392473/how-do-i-add-an-existing-directory-tree-to-a-project-in-visual-studio)

**Step #3**

Open **basic.html** from **demo** folder replace with this

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>WebcamJS Test Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; }
    h2, h3 { margin-top:0; }
    form { margin-top: 15px; }
    form > input { margin-right: 15px; }
    #results { float:right; margin:20px; padding:20px; border:1px solid; background:#ccc; }
</style>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>

<h1>WebcamJS Test Page</h1>
<h3>Demonstrates simple 320x240 capture &amp; display</h3>

<div id="my_camera"></div>

<!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../webcam.min.js"></script>

<!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
</script>

<!-- A button for taking snaps -->
<form>
    <input type=button id="takeshot" value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
</form>

<!-- Code to handle taking the snapshot and displaying it locally -->
<script language="JavaScript">

    window.onload = function () {

        setInterval(function () { take_snapshot() }, 5000);
    }
    function take_snapshot() {
        // take snapshot and get image data
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            // display results in page
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
                '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' + 
                '<img id="base64image" src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
        });



        var file = document.getElementById("base64image").src;

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("base64image", file);

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:26792/home/SaveImage",
            type: "POST",

            data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false


        });

    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1 /jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**Step #4**

Replace Home controller with

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

         string[] allimage = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"));
        if (allimage.Length>0)
        {
            List<string> base64text = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in allimage)
            {
                base64text.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(item.ToString()));
            }
            ViewBag.Images = base64text;
        }

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]

    public void SaveImage(string base64image)
    {
      System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + ".txt"), base64image);
    }
}
```

Finally replace Index.html with

```
<h2>Capture images</h2>

 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Images)
 {
   <img src="@item" />
 }
```

**Note**

This code 
will capture photo from webcam after every 5 second and save it to server as text file consist of [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode then Index action read them and and display as img src.

Answer (score -2):

WebRTC standard + using WebSockets / AJAX.

Comment: FYI, I didnt understand a damn thing... :| ANyways googling about it

Comment: @PratikBhoir it's a such API in Browser for JavaScript for communication in p2p and retrieving video/image streams from webcam.