# BundleTable.EnableOptimizations true breaks jquery-ui all.css

Tags: css, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

In an Asp.Net MVC 5 application, I am creating a style bundle in my `egisterBundles` method.
 I'm using `jquery-ui`.
  Instead of listing all of the `jquery-ui` css files individually I'm using `all.css`, which imports all the rest.
  The code looks like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/a.css",
                  "~/Content/b.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/base/all.css"));
```

And all.css contains two lines:

```
@import "base.css";
@import "theme.css";
```

This works, but only when I set

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false.
```

When I set

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true
```

then none of the jquery css loads.

Of course there is an easy workaround; I can individually add the jquery-ui css files to the bundle. 
  But I am curious:  why does all.css break when the css files are bundled and minified?
  This does not appear to be browser-specific, as I have the same problem in both *IE9* and *Chrome 39*.

Answer (score 4):

According to this answer the default minifier simply does not support the @import directive:

[MVC4 bundling CSS failed Unexpected token, found '@import'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970293/mvc4-bundling-css-failed-unexpected-token-found-import)

Also, the jquery-ui css files contain relative paths to images, so the virtual path of the bundle must allow the browser to find the relative path to the images, for example:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/jqueryui")
   .Include("~/Content/themes/base/core.css" [and other desired css files]));
```

And on the cshtml page:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jqueryui")
```

See this link for explication: [MVC4 StyleBundle not resolving images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355935/mvc4-stylebundle-not-resolving-images)

Comment: Interesting. I suppose it makes sense though. Given that the main point of the bundler is to combine all the listed files into one file, there's little point in supporting `@include`.

Comment: Yup, I had the same issue, and my solution was to get a list of all of the @import'd jQueryUI files, and add each of them into a bundles.Add() statement.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45083177/391605