# Local and deployed Web App seem to use different CSSs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Style.css on my MVC project as well as Bootstrap.css. In my BundleConfig I  do the following:

```
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/animate.css",
                  "~/Content/myproj/common.css",
                  "~/Content/style.css"));
```

and in my views I do:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that the fonts on my page when it is run locally looks a bit different from the one I have deployed to Azure. So when I looked at the devtools, on the Azure version there are a lot of references to bootstrap, but on the local I see it referring style tag. I attempt to attach screenshots here.

Can you please guide me on how I can fix this? Thank you.

[image: This is the local Devtools result]

[image: This is how it looks like locally]

[image: This is the Azure version]

[image: This is how it looks like when deployed to Azure]

Comment: You haven't really provided the code (css) that show what *font-family* you're trying to use.  It's possible you aren't deploying the font with your application.

Comment: @ErikPhilips thanks for the reply. I am not a front end dev, but by looking at the style.css, I see at the top the two line:import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700");
import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700");

Comment: Bundling may be removing `@import` or some how making it invalid.  It may not be the case but take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file).

Comment: @ErikPhilips thanks again. I believe that is what I am doing. It seems to be related to BundleTable.EnableOptimizations that jonathan has mentioned.

Comment: Pretty much [don't use @import if you're going to use the bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569633/bundletable-enableoptimizations-true-breaks-jquery-ui-all-css).

Comment: Thank you very much @ErikPhilips. Yes, I ended up removing those imports and added <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> to the top of my layout. If you promote your reply to solution I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you building debug locally, and release when you publish? If so, it might be because of different bundling behaviour for the different targets. See: [Bundling not working in MVC5 when I turn on release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254181/bundling-not-working-in-mvc5-when-i-turn-on-release-mode)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Jonathan. I think I am closer to the solution. So in my BundleConfig I have #if !DEBUG
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
#endif ...................If I set the above to false, then it will work as expected. But then I lose the benefit of optimization, don't I?

Comment: For what it's worth, I prefer to use Grunt / Compass for optimizations and bundling. I just find that I have had less issues with it versus the in-built Microsoft optimizer

Comment: No worries thank you. It will be a bit of scary change for me at this stage.

Comment: Finally I fixed this as there was a problem with my fonts and folder structure affecting the bundling.