# Automatically add all files in directory to library project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

We're looking to create a library to link several projects against in Visual Studio.  The source for this library is maintained outside of Visual Studio.  Is there a way to automatically scrape a specified directory (or directories) for *.cpp files and automatically add them to the library?  Currently we have to add or delete files as required (right click project, add, existing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer from (@Yuchen Zhong)

> In visual studio 2015, this is how you do it.
>
> If you wanted to automatically include all descendant files below a specific folder:
>
> ```
> <Content Include="Path\To\Folder\**" />
> ```
>
> Reference: http://jamesrpatterson.com/blog/automatic-include-in-project-for-visual-studio

from this SO question: [How do I add an existing directory tree to a project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392473/how-do-i-add-an-existing-directory-tree-to-a-project-in-visual-studio) should give you all you need.

```
<Content Include="Path\To\Folder\*.cpp" >
```

I knew the answer, and that it must be posted somewhere...took me a little bit to find, so hoping *this* answer helps others find the *other* answer.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2015, open in notepad the project file **project1.vcxproj**

In third line, (Under *< Project Default Target....... >*) Add:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="D:\MyCode\*.h" />
    <ClCompile Include="D:\MyCode\*.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
```