# Visual studio does't add new files to project when I merged other branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge

I have a git repository with two branch, **dev** and **featureA**

When I finished featureA so I merge it into dev, but featureA branch has some new files that dev does not have, like newFileA.cs and newFileB.cs, the problem is that the new files does not automatically added to the project in dev branch.

so, which steps I missed here?

I find the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392473/how-do-i-add-an-existing-directory-tree-to-a-project-in-visual-studio?rq=1) may be useful, but I don't want manually add each files every time there is a new file from another branch.

Comment: Did you add them in the feature branch? If you did, aren't you using some conflict resolution on .csproj files which could discard the additions?

Comment: @max630 I fingered it out. the file is added to feature branch, but the .csproj is not included in the feature branch, so merge doesn't have conflict

Comment: so, That means the project information is stored in .csproj file.  **But merge the .csproj file is another awful thing!**