# How to use user packages in Visual Studio 2017 in a python application

Tags: python, visual-studio, package, visual-studio-2017

[image: One]

I have this python application structure in Visual Studio 2017.
I created a `tests` folder using the Solution explorer and there's a `test.py` file in it.
I want to use the `test` module which is stored in `tests` directory. 
But when I try to use `import tests.test` it says `test` not defined.
I have just started learning python. 
I looked up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392473/how-do-i-add-an-existing-directory-tree-to-a-project-in-visual-studio) but I dont understand why isnt it working. Am I doing something wrong? I looked it up [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to import from from package. Each [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) must have an `__init__.py` file. You just have to add a blank file `__init__.py` to your `tests` folder and then it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks you very much. That was a stupid mistake of mine.