# How to add existing package in Python project in Visual Studio 2017 (for IntelliSense)

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

When I have a python project in VS 2017 and create a new python package (folder and __init__.py file) with the "Add->New File" menu, everything works as intended: IntelliSense recognized the package, I can import and use it.

But if I manually create a folder and __init__.py file, then I can still import and the code works fine, but IntelliSense is not picking up the new module. How can I manually include this existing package into the python project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perry Qian-MSFT's answer unfortunately did not work for me (more on that in the comment under his answer), but what did work was the same approach as **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392477/6793721)** to *[How do I add an existing directory tree to a project in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392477/)*?

[image: Step1]
[image: Step2]

Answer (score 1):

> How to add existing package in Python project in Visual Studio 2017
>   (for IntelliSense)

It is quite strange and it seems that you have created such folder in its physical path which contains a self-created file called `__init__.py`, but it works well in my side and I can get the Intellisense from the new module. You can follow my steps:

**Step**

**1)** I have created a folder called `package 3` and add a file called `__init__.py` under the physical path manually.

[image]

[image]

**2)** then open VS, start the project, right-click on it-->**Add**-->**Existing Folder**-->add **package 3** into it. Then it will import the package 3 folder and its content into Solution Explorer.

**3)** if you want to use new module in `package 3`'s `__init__.py`, you could use import node in **init**.py(package 3) :

`import module1;`

[image]

**In addition**, if Intellisense does not work either, you should close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under solution folder, then restart the project again to test it. You can try it several times.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I manually create the directory with a \_\_init__.py inside. `Right click on my project -> Add -> Existing Folder` and select the created directory, but then simply nothing happens. But using `Right click -> Include in project` on the directory after enabling `show all files` at the top works.