# Visual Studio 2019 shows netstandard2.0 projects as empty

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-standard-2.0

today I found that Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise edition shows netstandard2.0 projects as empty (it shows "Dependencies" node only.
I had 16.7.1 version, updated to 16.7.2 - no difference.
I was able to open the projects properly on earlier versions of VS.

Does anyone has the trouble? Might be it is not visual studio issue?
Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to remove .vs folder and restart ?

Comment: thank you for the hint - I tried, it didn't help.
i also cloned repo from scratch (without the .vs folder) - it didn't help as well

Comment: As a workaround I found following
In Solution Explorer click on "Show all files"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/392477/7404544

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I found following (it should work without it)
In Solution Explorer click on "Show all files"
then select needed
and after that by right clicking on selected items choose "Include In Project"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After not successful attempts to repair Visual Studio
I totally uninstalled it and installed it again using Visual Studio Installer
and right after that it started to work perfectly.

So if you faced similar problem and nothing helps,
try to reinstall visual studio, not just repair.