# Xamarin.iOS Archive fails after icon image changed

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Windows VS2019, with paired Mac. When I archive my Xamarin.iOS with default icon image, everything works, but when I replace images in asset catalog (only images, filenames are same) got this:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Users/Username/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Mealhint.Client.iOS/7dd3a1380dfc2b33cb9d05b42b9a01ca/obj/iPhone/Debug/actool/bundle/AppIcon60x60@2x.png"
> File name: '/Users/Username/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Mealhint.Client.iOS/7dd3a1380dfc2b33cb9d05b42b9a01ca/obj/iPhone/Debug/actool/bundle/AppIcon60x60@2x.png'
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00259] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:274
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:106
> at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions)
> at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile (System.String sourceFullPath, System.String destFullPath, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Unix.cs:54
> at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00056] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:74
> at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String target, System.String targetItemSpec) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.Core/Tasks/SmartCopyTaskBase.cs:68
> at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.Execute () [0x000a4] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.Core/Tasks/SmartCopyTaskBase.cs:101 Mealhint.Client.iOS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets   542

I tried to remove bin and obj, remove application cache on Mac and create new appicon asset, but I'm still getting this error... App works fine with new icon image on iPhoneSimulator.

Comment: Hi, you could have a look at this dicsussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64469773/appicon-is-not-being-found/64476586#64476586 , if be helpful, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by 24 bit depth image. Changing bit depth to 32 was the solution

Comment: Glad solved it. You could mark the answer when you can and it will be helpful for others who have the same issue.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I know, but I have to wait 20 more hours to accept it,