# How to add external libraries to python project in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

My python project has dependencies on packages that exist on the local file system in folder X (i.e. not installed form the internet). I'd like to add these packages (source code) to the python environment for my project. How can this be done?

I've add folder X to "Search Paths" in the Solution Explorer, but I still cannot import the package.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append(package_path)
import package
```

I import my packages from outside in this way, you can try this way.

you can take a look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392473/how-do-i-add-an-existing-directory-tree-to-a-project-in-visual-studio?rq=1) for include your project files into the your project

Comment: Understood, but is there no way within VS gui to add paths (as there is in pycharm)? I'd expect this to be a somewhat standard thing to do.