# how to add "Existing solution folder recursively" to my VS2005 solution

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I tried drag and drop from the explorer, but no luck with following error:

> "Folders cannot be dropped or pasted as solution items. Choose an individual document instead."

I know we can create each folders/subfolders manually and add each file, but any quick way to do this on visual studio 2005?

**Updated:** 
Thank you for the reply, but I do not want the folders to be added under any project, It should appear as a separate node inside my solution, like any other project. In this case the show all files does not work, since the solution itself does not have any folder, it is only if we select any project it works.

I know we can create each folders/subfolders manually and add each file, but any quick way, because there are few hundreds of files.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267200/visual-studio-solutions-folder-as-real-folders

Answer (score 5):

- Copy the folder in question into the local path of the project.
- Click the button in the VS Solution toolbar for "Show All Files"
- Click Refresh
- You should see this folder as a white icon.
- Right click on the folder, and select "Include in Project".

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I do not want folders to be added under any project, It should appear as separate node inside my solution, like any other project. In this case the show all files does not work, since the solution itself does not have any folder, it is only if we select any project it works.

Comment: Solutions are just collections of projects. You need to add it to a project.

Comment: And I spent 4 hours trying to figure out this... thanx man. =D