# Project file with just files and no built output

Tags: visual-studio

How can I make a project file (VS 2008) that just has some data files in and has no built output?

I can make an empty project and add my data files to it (which get copied to the output folder
), but it produces an EmptyProject.dll after I do a build. I want just my data files in the output directory and not some empty DLL or EXE.

I want the data files to be the only thing in this project as the project will be shared in a couple of solutions.

Our application is C#. All of our normal code projects are C#.

The data files are schemas (XSD). I want these schemas to be in the output folder, but I don't want them included with an existing project. I would like a project named "Schemas" that has nothing in except the XSD files and does nothing except copy the XSD files to the output folder. I would like this in a project file so that the same schemas project can be referenced in multiple solutions.

Comment: What type of project did you create? Can you create such a project with only a single file in it, then edit your question and post the project file here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a way to suppress the creation of the .dll file.  BUT... here's an easy workaround.  In the project properties, Build Events tab, write a Post-build event command line that will delete the file.  Something like:

del path\filename.dll

Comment: I thought of that, but I would guess that deleting the output would make the project build every time the solutions was built. not horrible, but not very elegant either.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Scott's answer:

1. Create a new project of type *Empty project*
2. In Properties->Application, change *Output type* to *Class Library*
3. In Properties->Build->Advanced, change *Debug Info* to *None*
4. In Properties->Build Events, set the *Post-build event command line* to `del $(TargetPath)`

That way, the project creates only a DLL, which gets deleted. At the same time, the "copy to output directory" settings on your data files is respected.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly another way is editing the csproj file by replacing this:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

with this:

```
  <Target Name="Build" />
  <Target Name="Rebuild" />
```

Then builds don't create anything. It worked for me.
Same general idea should work for any xxproj file. Just replace the `<Import Project...>` tags with the `<Target...>` tags.

I'd be interested in knowing if this causes any issues or doesn't work for anyone.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with the newer simplified csproj format. If I just remove the `Sdk` attribute from the `<Project>` element, VS downright refuses to open the project again.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need a project for if you're not building it?

1. You can use solution folders to "store" files...
2. Why not just disable building this project for all configurations (use the Configuration Manager) - that way it won't build.

Comment: We use it to have a "reference assemblies" project in our solution.  Several of the projects in our solution are independent and can compile on separate threads, but all compile to the same output folder and share the same references.  Rather than having each project's reference assemblies "copy local" and interfere with each other, we just have the reference project do it all.

Comment: Additionally Solution folders are "virtual folders" and can be pretty confusing because the solution folders don't match disk folders.

Comment: Concerning point 1), it doesn't look like files from those solution folders can be copied to the output folder during a build.

Answer (score 0):

Great stuff. Expanding on Scott > Daniel's answer:

- Safe to remove all References and Properties (AssemblyInfo.cs)
- If it is a node/grunt/gulp project then you can invoke it in your Build Events > *Post-build event command line * eg: `gulp build` or `gulp clean`
- Perhaps you can add removal or obj and bin output folders to your node/grunt/gulp clean scripts mitigating the need for  `del $(TargetPath)`