# How to add an existing folder on a solution level in vs 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I renamed a folder using Tortoise SVN which creates a new folder.
Now I want to add it again but there is no add existing folder option and I can't show all files at the solution level.
How can it be done?

EDIT:
I know that solution folders are virtual, I would like to import an existing hierachy.

Comment: It depends on if you mean a project's folder or a subfolder of an existing project (which does not have be changed on the solution level but on the project's level).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267200/visual-studio-solutions-folder-as-real-folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders on the solution level correspond to projects. So just [add the existing project file](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-VISUALSTUDIO-Add-Project-To-Solution) (.csproj, .vbproj, .vcproj) to your solution from the new folder (if you have a reference to the project at the old location in your solution, remove it first).

However, if you are talking about a subfolder within a project, quickest way to get it right is to open the project file with a simple text editor like notepad, find the old folder name within there and rename it manually.

Answer (score 1):

It cant be done. Solution folder are 'virtual'. Solution files are just links to the actual file location.