# why we are adding solution folder, and responsibilities share ,test folders inside solution

Tags: asp.net, data-access-layer, n-tier-architecture, 3-tier, bll

I have couple of the those pic I loaded.First my question about first pic.why those folders seems with dot presented.when I look ad those folsers,it says they are "solution folders".why we need this folder ,for example I am creating a class libabrary as a project.why should I decribe this project inside the "solution folders".

first pic.

[image]

second pic

[image]

my second question about this solution struture.which created by Layered Architecture Solution Guidance 2010 download from here http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8c473b5-21a1-447a-8b24-33b43411ee7f

It's already had bll,dal,bo, folder,why we need a share folder.which classes should  we put inside it and I also see a test folder.whats primary responsibilityies on this solution.and how it is used.
thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Question:  Those are solution folders, which are just a way of logically separating the different parts of the solution (layers, etc.).  You can only have physical folders inside a project (the ones that aren't dotted-lined): [Visual Studio Solutions Folder as real Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267200/visual-studio-solutions-folder-as-real-folders)

Second:  A shared folder could be used for classes that don't neatly fit inside either the BLL or the DAL.  I can't think of a reason off the top of my head for one, but I've seen examples where shared classes are created in RIA services for Silverlight.

Bonus: The tests folder is for holding your Unit Tests.  Look up Unit Testing for ideas.  It is very useful to write Unit Tests for your code to provide a first line of bug-fighting whenever you create (do my tests run successfully on my new code?) or modify (do my tests **still** run successfully on my existing code after this change I just made).  **NUnit** is a popular open-source Unit Test framework, and MS provides its own **Test Project** Unit Test framework built into Visual Studio.

Comment: but problem still the same , I can also logically separating the different parts of the solution,using the real folders(physical folders),why do u need virtual folders and why I use them

Comment: You can't do it natively in Visual Studio in a solution.  You don't even get the option from a solution.

Comment: upsss,u are right sorry ,I just though that I could create new project not using inside the folder.okey,thnak u u are right again