# Sync Visual Studio 2008 solution folder structure with file system structure

Tags: parsing, visual-studio-2008, synchronization, solution, file-structure

A I mentioned Visual Studio [cannot treat solution folder as real folder on disc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267200/444079).

How can I deal, if I want to sync VS2008 solution folders with file system structure?

Should/Can I edit solution file manually? Is there 3rd party tools with syntax/semantic checking? With more verbose warning messages as standard:

[image: Visual Studio 2008 cannot recognize solution folder structure after editing]

P.S. May be also Visual Studio macro?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Solutions Folder as real Folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267200/visual-studio-solutions-folder-as-real-folders) - did you at least try the macro of the second answer?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to create filters for use in C# projects. Do you mean macro from book "Professional Visual Studio Extensibility" page 502?

Comment: No I mean the macro `GenerateSlnFolderOnDirStructure` in VS->Macro Explorer->Samples->AddDirAsSlnFolder. Didn't try it myself, but it says *Macro to import a folder on disk into a solution folder structure.* which seems exactly what you are after

Comment: OK thanks. I found it. But this macro is also described in this book.