# Create actual physical folders in Visual Studio solution

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I would like to follow ASP.NET 5 solution structure from here https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/ed7564297c61fe9ab814

How do you create actual physical folders in Visual Studio 2015 RC solution? How do you create for example "tests" folder, that is physically at the same level as "src" folder created by default with a new ASP.NET 5 website project? And, of course, I would like to be able to place projects into it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Solutions Folder as real Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267200/visual-studio-solutions-folder-as-real-folders)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a solution:

1. Create "Solution folder" named "tests". This will create logical folder, but not physical one.
2. Right click to the solution folder and open a new project dialog. But before you click OK, you have to change a project location to your desired physical folder and VS will create it and place the project inside.

This is not very intuitive, but it works.

Comment: How to update the same, If we are moving existing projects to that newly created folder