# Add Existing Files to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Duplicate: [How to "Add Existing Item" an entire directory structure in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776/how-to-add-existing-item-an-entire-directory-structure-in-visual-studio)

I am adding existing files to my web application.  The directory structure is fairly complex.  Is there a way to add this entire directory structure without manually adding each folder and file to the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project you want to add the directory and files to and click on the button at the top of the solution explorer called "Show All Files" (the second one from the left). This should show you all of the files on disk, whether or not they are included in your solution.

If you now find the directory you want to include, you can right-click on it and select "Include in Project". This will include the directory and everything inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

When you select a file/folder, choose 'Add as link' instead of 'Add'

Comment: I can't seem to find the 'Add as Link' command. When I right click on the folder in solution explorer I only get the add menu item with the new item, existing item or folder options.

Comment: Yes, say add existing item, select the files, then next to the 'add' button there's a little triangle, which makes a further drop-down with 'add as link', you can use this to add existing items which are not 'under' the current directory.