# in VS2010 how do I add a whole directory of existing items

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 how do I add a whole directory of existing items?

When I right click on project and Add ExistingItem I seem to be able to load only one file at a time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "Add Existing Item" an entire directory structure in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776/how-to-add-existing-item-an-entire-directory-structure-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming the files are already in the proper project's directory

1. Select the project in solution explorer
2. Click "Show All Files" icon at the top of solution explorer
3. Right click on the folder you want to be part of the solution
4. Select the "Include in project" option
5. ??
6. Profit!!!

Just kidding about 5 and 6, but that's probably the easiest way if the files are in the right directory structure, otherwise Andy's solution is probably easiest.