# phonegap windows phone copy existing www over?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, buildaction

I have created a phonegap windows phone project, did the install and setup. It runs fine with the demo/default code when I run the emulator.
I have an existing android project. I drag my www folder to the windows project and nothing works.
The manifestprocessor.js does not build any of the new files in the xml. When I right click my new files I do **not** have an option to select a build action. I do not get any errors on the build. I want to also note that my default htnl file should load login.html (I updated the CordovaView.xaml.cs file) and the cordova.js files is inside the "js" folder in www, not on the root like the default setup.

Anyone have any ideas? I have never developed using visual studio, I am guessing I need to get my new files to be recognize so I can assign build actions I guess but since it won't let me I am not sure what to do, or even if that is the problem.

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776/how-to-add-existing-item-an-entire-directory-structure-in-visual-studio][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776/how-to-add-existing-item-an-entire-directory-structure-in-visual-studio

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/57788/255654