# Visual Studio 2010: add existing folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I want to use lots of stuff that is already created and is stored in a folder.
In a new project I want to use that classes and just add the whole folder,
including the folder itself to keep the project clearly arranged.

How can I add an existing folder to a project?

As the folder is on a concurrent versions system, I do not want to copy / move / create the files and especially the folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "Add Existing Item" an entire directory structure in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776/how-to-add-existing-item-an-entire-directory-structure-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you not "Show all files" in the solution explorer to see the folders and files not in the project, then "Include In Project"

...or did I not understand the question?

Comment: No, you are exactly right! Thank you! Just forgot about the filtering.