# How can I add a whole directory structure into a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, architecture, solution, visual-studio-2015

There's a directory structure (the root folder and a bunch of subfolders with their subfolders in them etc.) and I'd like to keep these in our TFS, as a part of the solution, even if those are not source code files and don't belong to a project.

Optimally, those would be listed as "others" or "solution files". However, I can put them in a project if there's a suitable type of such.

When I tried to add these to the solution, the root directory's files get added but none of the subfolders nor the files in the subfolders. Is it possible to add a non-shallow directory structure to a solution somehow?

[image]

As the image depicts, there's a folder called *Misc*. In that folder, only the files from the root directory get added. How can I add the whole structure with its depth preserved? Or is there a more appropriate way to keep such files within a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "Add Existing Item" an entire directory structure in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776/how-to-add-existing-item-an-entire-directory-structure-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How do I add an existing directory tree to a project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392473/how-do-i-add-an-existing-directory-tree-to-a-project-in-visual-studio)

1. Add the folders to your folder directory
2. Show all files
3. Include the subdirectory in the solution

Comment: I'm not sure if you got the question correctly. I wish to add the root folder **and** the subfolders in one operation. Adding a large number of subfolders with their subsubfolders etc. is not something that is sany to do one by one. Also, give that the linked question's been asked 2008, I'm hoping that there's some new features in VS 2013 or 2015.