# Visual C++: cannot "Go To Document", although file is part of the project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, include

In an empty Visual Studio C++ project, I added a source file tree containing source and header files simply by dragging and **dropping the root dir** onto my project in the VS Solution Explorer.

When I pick an `#include <mylib.h>` statement in a source file and choose "**Go To Document**" in the context menu, I get a message

> File 'mylib.h' **not found** in current source file's directory or in build system paths

although the file occurs in the project tree under "Header Files".

---

Interestingly, when I pick a function in the same source file and choose "**Find All References**" in the context menu, I get **results also from this header** file mylib.h (a forward declaration).

---

How to convince Visual Studio to be able to open all header files in my project?

In my case it does not care, whether the real effective include dir list for each source is reproduced by VS. I just want to use VS as a source navigator. So adding all directories containing header files to my project's "Include Directories" list (or other "build system paths"?) would be sufficient.
How to achieve this for a complex source tree with minimal effort?

Comment: I have this problem for a CMake-generated project with Conan-installed dependencies, where everything works (building, debugging, IntelliSense) except "Go to Document". It looks like someone reported an issue with resolving relative paths to Microsoft a year ago and that there is at least a partial fix, but only for VS 2022 (VS 2019 is on extended support so no fixes anymore I suppose): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-studio-STILL-cant-resolve-rela/10127269 - not sure if it's the same issue, however. In my case, all of the paths in .vcxproj are absolute to the include dirs

Comment: If you use CMake, the workaround I found is to do `set_target_properties(myTarget PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_ExternalIncludePath "${BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIRS};$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);")` to populate the "External Include Directories" option of a specific CMake target. In the example, I add the BZip2 include path, with the `${BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIRS}` variable being set by `find_package()`. This makes "Go to Document" work but I don't know if this has negative effects as well. See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23834 and https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22163